# Obtain All Firebase Child and Value and Show on HTML

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to obtain ALL of the child's data from Firebase and show the data on an unordered List in HTML. Currently, I can only obtain the data for child "hobbies". How can I obtain all of the child values under "object" without hard coding in 'hobbies'? Below is my App.js file:

```
  (function() {

    //Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
        apiKey: "AIjjjewjfjewjfjwefwefew",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket:"xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //Get elements
    const preObject = document.getElementById('object');
    const ulList = document.getElementById('list');
    var UID = ' ';
    var UIDArray = [];

    //Create refences
    const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
    const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child('hobbies');

    dbRefObject.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    var keys = childSnapshot.key;
    var values = childSnapshot.val();
    var name = values['Name'];
    var credit = values['Credits'];

    console.log(keys); //keys
    console.log(values); //values 
    console.log(name);//name
    console.log(credit);//name

    });
  });
    //const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child(UID);

    //Sync object changes
    dbRefList.on('value', snap => {
        preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);

    });

    //Sync list changes
    dbRefList.on('child_added', snap => {

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = snap.val();
        li.id = snap.key;
        var keyValue = snap.key;

        ulList.appendChild(li);

    });

    dbRefList.on('child_changed', snap => {

        const liChanged = document.getElementById(snap.key);
        liChanged.innerText = snap.val();
    });

    dbRefList.on('child_removed', snap => {

        const liToRemove = document.getElementById(snap.key);
        liToRemove.remove();
    });

}());
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the help! I was able to console.log it and get all of the values out! On a second note, if I wanted to "listen" for the changes such as when something was added,deleted or changed in the database and I wanted to show in the HTML list, how would I achieve that? I changed everything to dbRefObject.on(child_changed', childSnapshot => ), child_removed', childSnapshot =>, etc but doesn't seem to work. I tried to change what I had before to the following:

```
(function() {

const config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "dxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket:"xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    };
    //Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //Get elements
    const preObject = document.getElementById('object');
    const ulList = document.getElementById('list');
    var UID = ' ';
    var UIDArray = [];

    //Create refences
    const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
    const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child('hobbies');

    dbRefObject.once("value").then(function(allSnapshot) {
        allSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    var keys = childSnapshot.key;
    var values = childSnapshot.val();
    var name = values['Name'];
    var credit = values['Credits'];
    var location = values['Location'];

    console.log(keys); //keys
    console.log(values); //values 
    console.log(name);//name
    console.log(credit);//name
    console.log(location);//name
    ulList.append(" ",name, " " , credit, " ", location );

    });
    });
  });

    //Sync object changes
    dbRefObject.on('value', childSnapshot => {
        preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val(), null, 3);

    });

    //Sync list changes
    dbRefObject.on('child_added', childSnapshot => {

        console.log(childSnapshot.val())
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = childSnapshot.val();
        li.id = childSnapshot.key;
        var keyValue = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(keyValue);
        ulList.appendChild(li);

    });

    dbRefObject.on('child_changed', childSnapshot => {
        console.log(childSnapshot.val());
        console.log(childSnapshot.key);
        const liChanged = document.getElementById(childSnapshot.key);
        liChanged.innerText = childSnapshot.val();

    });

    dbRefObject.on('child_removed', childSnapshot => {

        const liToRemove = document.getElementById(childSnapshot.key);
        liToRemove.remove();
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load all data under `dbRefObject`, instead of just `hobbies` you can do:

```
const dbAllList = dbRefObject;

dbRefObject.once("value").then(function(allSnapshot) {
  allSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      ...
```

The changes are fairly simple:

1. I removed the `child('hobbies')` call from the reference you listen to, meaning that the `once('value'` will now return all data from one level higher in the JSON tree.
2. I added an additional `allSnapshot.forEach(...)` loop inside the callback, to loop over all children that are now returned.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I was able to console.log it correctly out. How do I listen for the changes such as removed, added, etc? Edited Code has been placed under original question above.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. But if you want to get notified of events of individual child nodes, listen to the individual `child_*` events as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events. You'll need to remove the `forEach` loop, since you'll be triggered by nodes one level lower in the JSOn that way.